# JSF 1.2 when invoke bean method by h:commandButton, it does not works all the time

Tags: jsf, backing-beans

Recently, I have met a really weird problem. It is as follows:
In the save page of a typical CRUD workflow, clicking the h:commandButton to call the save method in backing end bean does not work all the time. Sometimes, it works as I expected finishing the method I direct in bean. In the other occasions, it just creates new Bean without enter update mode phase, needless to say it enters the bean method. There are no error messages shown in the console, only some suspected statements like: [component] No renderer-type for component j_id26, etc.

I tried to solve it by assigning all of JSF html tag a id. However, it looks like in vain. Even I can't reproduce with a fixed manner. Too random to grasp the fundamental error principles.

Because the page source is a little bit huge. Let me confirm whether you guys have similar problems, then I will take a further step to show more clues whichever it needs.

Thanks in advance.

The code as follows:
1.graphtemplate.xhtml

```
........
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="tdBtnSave"><h:commandButton id="invisibleBtnSave"
                action="#{graphTemplate.save}" style="display: none">
            </h:commandButton>
            <button type="button" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="step5Save">SAVE</button>
            </td>
            <td>
            <button type="button" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="step5Cancel">CANCEL</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p />
```

.............

2.GraphTemplateBean.java

```
/**
* 
* @author Freeman Bo Ye
* 
*/
public class GraphTemplateBean extends ThinBeanBase {

public Integer id = null;
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/*
 * y, x axis data (step 1)
 */
private List<String> yAxes = new ArrayList<String>(); // y axes
private Integer yScaleType = null; // y axis scale type
private Boolean yScaleIsAuto = null; // y axis scale is auto
private Double yCustomNumStart = null; // y custom start
private Double yCustomNumEnd = null; // y custom end
private Double yCustomNumTicMarks = null; // y custom tic marks
private String xAxis = null; // x axis
private Integer xScaleType = null; // x axis scale type
private Boolean xScaleIsAuto = null; // x axis scale is auto
private Date xCustomDateStart = null; // x axis custom date start
private Double xCustomNumStart = null; // x axis custom number start
private Date xCustomDateEnd = null; // x axis custom date end
private Double xCustomNumEnd = null; // x axis custom number end
private Integer xCustomDateTicMarks = null; // x custom date tic marks
private Double xCustomNumTicMarks = null; // x custom number tic marks
/*
 * graph titles (step 2)
 */
private List<String> graphTitles = new ArrayList<String>(); // graph titles
private String graphCustomTitle = null; // graph custom title
private Integer graphTitleFontSize = null; // graph title font size
private Color graphTitleColor = null; // graph title color
private List<Integer> graphTitleStyles = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // graph title styles
private Boolean isMultiLines = null; // is multiple lines
private String yTitle = null; // y title
private String yCustomTitle = null; // y custom title
private Integer yTitleFontSize = null; // y title font size
private Color yTitleColor = null; // y title color
private List<Integer> yTitleStyles = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // y title styles
private String xTitle = null; // x title
private String xCustomTitle = null; // x custom title
private Integer xTitleFontSize = null; // x title font size
private Color xTitleColor = null; // x title color
private List<Integer> xTitleStyles = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // x title styles
/*
 * line styles (step 3)
 */
private List<LineStyle> lineStyles = new ArrayList<LineStyle>(); // line styles
/*
 * define legend (step 4)
 */
private Boolean isShowUserLegend = null;
private List<String> legendTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
private Integer userLegendFontSize = null;
private Color userLegendColor = null;
private List<Integer> userLegendStyles = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private Boolean isShowDataLegend = null;
private Integer dataLegendFontSize = null;
private Color dataLegendColor = null;
private List<Integer> dataLegendStyles = new ArrayList<Integer>();
/*
 * name and extra properties (step 5)
 */
private String name = null; // graph template name

private List<Integer> extraProps = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // graph template's extra properties

public GraphTemplateBean() {
    logger.debug("new graph template bean request......");
    for (SelectItem selectItem : getAllYAxes()) {
        LineStyle lineStyle = new LineStyle();
        lineStyle.setyAxis(selectItem.getLabel());
        lineStyles.add(lineStyle);
    }
    logger.info("GraphTemplateBean is created.");
}

..............

/**
 * Get creating type from scratch or saved graph template.
 * 
 * @return from scratch or saved
 */
public List<SelectItem> getFromScratchOrSaved() {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    result.add(new SelectItem(true, "Create new graph from scratch"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(false, "Start with saved graph:"));
    return result;
}

/**
 * All graph templates
 * 
 * @return all graph templates
 * @throws GraphServiceException
 */
public List<SelectItem> getAllGraphTemplates() throws GraphServiceException {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    GraphService gs = GraphServiceFactory.getInstance(getUser());
    List<MyTemplate> graphTemplates = gs.listMyTemplate();
    for (MyTemplate graphTemplate : graphTemplates) {
        result.add(new SelectItem(graphTemplate.getId(), graphTemplate.getName()));
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * all y axes.
 * 
 * @return all y axes
 */
public List<SelectItem> getAllYAxes() {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    result.add(new SelectItem("Oil (bbl)", "Oil (bbl)"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Gas (mcf)", "Gas (mcf)"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Water (bbl)", "Water (bbl)"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Injection", "Injection"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Historical Well Count", "Historical Well Count"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Cumulative Oil (bbl)", "Cumulative Oil (bbl)"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Cumulative Gas (mcf)", "Cumulative Gas (mcf)"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Cumulative Water (bbl)", "Cumulative Water (bbl)"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Cumulative Injection", "Cumulative Injection"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Annual Oil (bbl)", "Annual Oil (bbl)"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Annual Gas (mcf)", "Annual Gas (mcf)"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Annual Water (bbl)", "Annual Water (bbl)"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Annual Injection", "Annual Injection"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Water Cut", "Water Cut"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Oil Cut", "Oil Cut"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Gas/Oil Ratio", "Gas/Oil Ratio"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Yield", "Yield"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Water/Oil Ratio", "Water/Oil Ratio"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Oil/Water Ratio", "Oil/Water Ratio"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Water/Gas Ratio", "Water/Gas Ratio"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Oil/Injection Ratio", "Oil/Injection Ratio"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Injection/Oil Ratio", "Injection/Oil Ratio"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Injection/(Oil+Water)", "Injection/(Oil+Water)"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("(Oil+Water)/Injection", "(Oil+Water)/Injection"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Injection/Gas Ratio", "Injection/Gas Ratio"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Gas/Injection Ratio", "Gas/Injection Ratio"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Bottom Hole Pressure", "Bottom Hole Pressure"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Flowing Pressure", "Flowing Pressure"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Tubing Pressure", "Tubing Pressure"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("BHP/Z Pressure", "BHP/Z Pressure"));
    return result;
}

/**
 * all y, x axis scales.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public List<SelectItem> getAllScaleTypes() {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    result.add(new SelectItem(0, "Linear"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(1, "Logarithmic"));
    return result;
}

/**
 * all y, x axis scale configurations.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public List<SelectItem> getScaleAutoOrCustom() {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    result.add(new SelectItem(true, "Automatically scale to fit data"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(false, "Custom scale"));
    return result;
}

/**
 * all x axes.
 * 
 * @return all x axes
 */
public List<SelectItem> getAllXAxes() {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    result.add(new SelectItem("Time", "Time"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Cumulative Oil (bbl)", "Cumulative Oil   (bbl)"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Cumulative Gas (mcf)", "Cumulative Gas   (mcf)"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Cumulative Water (bbl)", "Cumulative Water   (bbl)"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Cumulative Injection", "Cumulative   Injection"));
    return result;
}

/**
 * all graph titles.
 * 
 * @return all graph titles
 */
public List<SelectItem> getAllGraphTitles() {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    result.add(new SelectItem("Custom", "Custom"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Production ID", "Production ID"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Lease Name", "Lease Name"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Well Number", "Well Number"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("API Number", "API Number"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("API Unique Number", "API Unique Number"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Operator", "Operator"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("First Production Date", "First Production Date"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Last Production Date", "Last Production Date"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Lease Type", "Lease Type"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Lease Status", "Lease Status"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Cumulative Oil", "Cumulative Oil"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Cumulative Gas", "Cumulative Gas"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Cumulative Water", "Cumulative Water"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Cumulative Injection", "Cumulative Injection"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("State", "State"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("County", "County"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Field", "Field"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Reservoir", "Reservoir"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Producing Zone", "Producing Zone"));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Location", "Location"));
    return result;
}

/**
 * all font sizes.
 * 
 * @return all font sizes
 */
public List<SelectItem> getAllFontSizes() {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    result.add(new SelectItem(8, "8px"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(10, "10px"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(12, "12px"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(14, "14px"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(16, "16px"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(18, "18px"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(20, "20px"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(25, "25px"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(30, "30px"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(35, "35px"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(40, "40px"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(45, "45px"));
    return result;
}

/**
 * all styles.
 * 
 * @return all styles
 */
public List<SelectItem> getAllStyles() {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    result.add(new SelectItem(0, "Bold"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(1, "Italic"));
    return result;
}

/**
 * all y titles.
 * 
 * @return all y titles
 */
public List<SelectItem> getAllYTitles() {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    if (yAxes.size() == 0)
        result.addAll(getAllYAxes());
    else {
        for (String yAxis : yAxes) {
            result.add(new SelectItem(yAxis, yAxis));
        }
    }
    result.add(new SelectItem("Custom Title", "< Custom Title >"));
    return result;
}

/**
 * all x titles.
 * 
 * @return all x titles
 */
public List<SelectItem> getAllXTitles() {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    if (xAxis == null)
        result.addAll(getAllXAxes());
    else
        result.add(new SelectItem(xAxis, xAxis));
    result.add(new SelectItem("Custom Title", "< Custom Title >"));
    return result;
}

/**
 * all line scales.
 * 
 * @return all line scales
 */
public List<SelectItem> getAllLineScales() {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    result.add(new SelectItem(0.0329, "Daily"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(0.01, "X 0.01"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(0.1, "X 0.1"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(1.0, "X 1"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(10.0, "X 10"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(100.0, "X 100"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(1000.0, "X 1,000"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(10000.0, "X 10,000"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(100000.0, "X 100,000"));
    return result;
}

/**
 * all label positions.
 * 
 * @return all label positions
 */
public List<SelectItem> getAllLabelPositions() {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    result.add(new SelectItem(0, "Line Start"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(1, "Line End"));
    return result;
}

/**
 * all legend titles.
 * 
 * @return all legend titles
 */
public List<SelectItem> getAllLegendTitles() {
    List<SelectItem> result = getAllGraphTitles();
    result.remove(0);
    return result;
}

/**
 * all extra properties.
 * 
 * @return all extra properties
 */
public List<SelectItem> getAllExtraProps() {
    List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    result.add(new SelectItem(0, "Make this the default graph on the view Records page"));
    result.add(new SelectItem(1, "Allow other people in my company to use this graph"));
    return result;
}

private List<Integer> convertStylesAsList(int nStyles) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    switch (nStyles) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        result.add(0);
        break;
    case 4:
        result.add(1);
        break;
    case 5:
        result.add(0);
        result.add(1);
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "The title sytle is not correct configured, probably the underlying graph template file is corrupted!");
    }
    return result;
}

private int convertStylesAsInteger(List<Integer> listStyle) {
    assert (listStyle != null);
    int result = 0;
    for (Integer style : listStyle) {
        switch (style) {
        case 0:
            result += 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            result += 4;
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet");
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private List<Integer> convertLabelPositionsAsList(int nLabelPositions) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    switch (nLabelPositions) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        result.add(0);
        break;
    case 2:
        result.add(1);
        break;
    case 3:
        result.add(0);
        result.add(1);
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "The line sytle's lable positions is not correct configured, probably the underlying graph template file is corrupted!");
    }
    return result;
}

private int convertLabelPositionsAsInteger(List<Integer> listLabelPosition) {
    assert (listLabelPosition != null);
    int result = 0;
    for (Integer labelPosition : listLabelPosition) {
        switch (labelPosition) {
        case 0:
            result += 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            result += 2;
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet");
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public String create() throws GraphServiceException {
    logger.debug("create graph template......");
    /*
     * y, x axis data (step 1)
     */
    yAxes.add("Oil (bbl)");
    yScaleType = 1;
    yScaleIsAuto = true;
    xAxis = "Time";
    xScaleType = 0;
    xScaleIsAuto = true;
    /*
     * graph titles (step 2)
     */
    graphTitles.add("Lease Name");
    graphTitles.add("Well Number");
    graphTitles.add("API Number");
    graphTitleFontSize = 10;
    graphTitleColor = Color.BLACK;
    isMultiLines = false;
    yTitleFontSize = 10;
    yTitleColor = Color.BLACK;
    xTitleFontSize = 10;
    xTitleColor = Color.BLACK;
    /*
     * line styles (step 3)
     */
    for (LineStyle lineStyle : lineStyles) {
        lineStyle.setInUse(yAxes.contains(lineStyle.getyAxis()) ? true : false);
        lineStyle.setLineStyle(0);
        lineStyle.setLineScale(1.0);
        if (lineStyle.getyAxis().endsWith("Oil (bbl)"))
            lineStyle.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        else if (lineStyle.getyAxis().endsWith("Gas (mcf)"))
            lineStyle.setColor(Color.RED);
        else if (lineStyle.getyAxis().endsWith("Water (bbl)"))
            lineStyle.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        else if ("Water/Oil Ratio".equals(lineStyle.getyAxis()))
            lineStyle.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        else
            lineStyle.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        lineStyle.setLabelPositions(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
    /*
     * Define Legend (step 4)
     */
    isShowUserLegend = false;
    legendTitles.addAll(graphTitles);
    userLegendFontSize = 10;
    userLegendColor = Color.BLACK;
    isShowDataLegend = false;
    dataLegendFontSize = 10;
    dataLegendColor = Color.BLACK;
    /*
     * name and extra properties (step 5)
     */
    int max = 0;
    for (SelectItem selectItem : getAllGraphTemplates()) {
        if (selectItem.getLabel().indexOf("My Graph Template ") != -1
                && patInteger.matcher(selectItem.getLabel().substring(18)).matches()) {
            int sequence = Integer.parseInt(selectItem.getLabel().substring(18));
            if (sequence > max)
                max = sequence;
        }
    }
    name = "My Graph Template " + (max + 1);
    return "create";
}

public String save() throws GraphServiceException {
    logger.debug("save graph template......");
    GraphService gs = GraphServiceFactory.getInstance(getUser());
    GraphConfiguration graphConfiguration = null;
    MyTemplate myTemplate = null;
    if(id==0)
        id= null;
    if (id != null) {
        gs.setTemplateId(id);
        gs.loadGraphTemplate();
    }
    graphConfiguration = new GraphConfiguration();
    /*
     * y, x axis data (step 1)
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < yAxes.size(); i++) {
        GraphSeries graphSeries = new GraphSeries();
        graphSeries.setId(i + 1);
        AxisInfo yAxisInfo = new AxisInfo();
        yAxisInfo.setName(yAxes.get(i));
        yAxisInfo.setType(yScaleType);
        yAxisInfo.setAutoScale(yScaleIsAuto);
        if (!yScaleIsAuto) {
            yAxisInfo.setStartValue(yCustomNumStart.toString());
            yAxisInfo.setEndValue(yCustomNumEnd.toString());
            yAxisInfo.setTicks(yCustomNumTicMarks);
        }
        graphSeries.setY(yAxisInfo);
        AxisInfo xAxisInfo = new AxisInfo();
        xAxisInfo.setName(xAxis);
        xAxisInfo.setType(xScaleType);
        xAxisInfo.setAutoScale(xScaleIsAuto);
        if (!xScaleIsAuto) {
            boolean isTime = "Time".equals(xAxis);
            xAxisInfo.setStartValue(isTime ? yearFormat.format(xCustomDateStart) : xCustomNumStart.toString());
            xAxisInfo.setEndValue(isTime ? yearFormat.format(xCustomDateEnd) : xCustomNumEnd.toString());
            xAxisInfo.setTicks(isTime ? xCustomDateTicMarks : xCustomNumTicMarks);
        }
        graphSeries.setX(xAxisInfo);
        graphConfiguration.addSeries(graphSeries);
    }
    /*
     * graph titles (step 2)
     */
    GraphTitle graphTitle = new GraphTitle();
    for (String tmp : graphTitles)
        graphTitle.addStandardData(!"Custom".equals(tmp) ? tmp : graphCustomTitle);
    graphTitle.setSize(graphTitleFontSize);
    graphTitle.setColor(colorConverter.getAsString(null, null, graphTitleColor));
    graphTitle.setStyle(convertStylesAsInteger(graphTitleStyles));
    graphTitle.setMultiline(isMultiLines);
    AxisLabel yAxisLabel = new AxisLabel();
    yAxisLabel.setName(!"Custom Title".equals(yTitle) ? yTitle : yCustomTitle);
    yAxisLabel.setSize(yTitleFontSize);
    yAxisLabel.setColor(colorConverter.getAsString(null, null, yTitleColor));
    yAxisLabel.setStyle(convertStylesAsInteger(yTitleStyles));
    AxisLabel xAxisLabel = new AxisLabel();
    xAxisLabel.setName(!"Custom Title".equals(xTitle) ? xTitle : xCustomTitle);
    xAxisLabel.setSize(xTitleFontSize);
    xAxisLabel.setColor(colorConverter.getAsString(null, null, xTitleColor));
    xAxisLabel.setStyle(convertStylesAsInteger(xTitleStyles));
    graphConfiguration.setTitle(graphTitle);
    graphConfiguration.setYLabel(yAxisLabel);
    graphConfiguration.setXLabel(xAxisLabel);
    /*
     * line styles (step 3)
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < lineStyles.size(); i++) {
        LineStyle lineStyle = lineStyles.get(i);
        if (lineStyle.getInUse()) {
            Line line = new Line();
            line.setSeries(i + 1);
            line.setStyle(lineStyle.getLineStyle());
            line.setScale(lineStyle.getLineScale());
            line.setColor(colorConverter.getAsString(null, null, lineStyle.getColor()));
            line.setLabel(convertLabelPositionsAsInteger(lineStyle.getLabelPositions()));
            line.setLegend(true);
            graphConfiguration.addLine(line);
        }
    }
    /*
     * define legend (step 4)
     */
    if (isShowUserLegend) {
        UserLegend userLegend = new UserLegend();
        for (String legendTitle : legendTitles) {
            userLegend.addStandardData(legendTitle);
        }
        userLegend.setSize(userLegendFontSize);
        userLegend.setColor(colorConverter.getAsString(null, null, userLegendColor));
        userLegend.setStyle(convertStylesAsInteger(userLegendStyles));
        graphConfiguration.setUserLegend(userLegend);
    }
    if (isShowDataLegend) {
        DataLegend dataLegend = new DataLegend();
        dataLegend.setSize(dataLegendFontSize);
        dataLegend.setColor(colorConverter.getAsString(null, null, dataLegendColor));
        dataLegend.setStyle(convertStylesAsInteger(dataLegendStyles));
        graphConfiguration.setDataLegend(dataLegend);
    }
    /*
     * name and extra properties (step 5)
     */
    myTemplate = (id == null ? new MyTemplate() : gs.getTemplate());
    myTemplate.setName(name);
    myTemplate.setPath(getUser().getHomeDirectory() + GraphConfiguration.PATH + name);
    for (Integer extraProp : extraProps) {
        switch (extraProp) {
        case 0:
            myTemplate.setDefault(true);
            break;
        case 1:
            myTemplate.setPublic(MyTemplate.PUBLIC);
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet!");
        }
    }
    // save...
    if (id == null) {
        logger.info("new graph template......");
        gs.insertMyTemplate(graphConfiguration, myTemplate);
    } else {
        logger.info("update graph template(id) " + id);
        gs.updateMyTemplate(graphConfiguration, myTemplate);
    }
    return "success";
}
```

....................

Answer (score 1):

When you click the `h:commandButton` in a  form, the request should pass through at least the following checking before the *Update Model Phase* and the bean's method runs.

1. If the <html> form has the onsubmit() event handler, it should return true.
2. *Apply Request Values Phase* converts the HTTP parameters, which are the string you enter in the UI, to the java type that the UI component object can hold. For example, if you enter all characters for the number UI component and  these characters cannot be converted to a number, errors will be produced .
3. If you specify some validation attribute in the UI tags, the *Process Validation Phase* will validate the value you entered according to these validation attribute. For example, if you enter 1000 for the following input, errors will be produced.

   ```
   <h:inputText id="userNo" value="#{UserNumberBean.userNumber}">
   <f:validateLongRange minimum="0" maximum="10" /> 
   </h:inputText>
   ```

Comment: except </h:messages>, is there any other way to debug JSF lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

Is the bean serialized ?
have you used `<t:savestate>` or something of that nature, it seems that could solve that issue.

please post the code of your button

Comment: Hi Aba, really appreciate your answer, I added the code snippet above. I use dojo javascript to click hidden jsf button to submit the form. Please diagnose it. Probably, little bit messy up. Let me clean up it right away.

Comment: sorry, I don't use myfaces library.

Answer (score 0):

Check carefully for validation errors. For debug purposes try to print all validation messages and see if your form fails to submit.
Use `<h:messages/>`.

Comment: Hi mmanco, Thank you for your answer. Does the <h:messages/> also show in web server's console? I need not find error message in my console, so the <h:messages/> will show nothing as well?

Comment: No the <h:messages/> is a component that renders all messages as HTML. Therefore, you will not see any messages printed to the console.

Comment: JSF 1.2 and newer will however by default issue WARN logs whenever a message is never been rendered.

Comment: when the problem happens, even the <h:messages/> show nothing. What does it imply? very strange.

Comment: probably, I use request scope instead of session scope, so the the <h:messages/> show nothing. Let me fix it.